# How to call all activity onDestroy() when MainAcitivty call onDestroy()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I made two activities for the test.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubActivity.class));
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

This button in MainActivity can start SubActivity.

```
public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SubActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

When in SubActivity, press back button, it doesn't call `onDestroy()` in **SubActivity** class and start MainActivity. What I want to do is, How to call SubActivity `onDestroy()` when I finish the MainActivity? It doesn't call SubActivity `onDestroy()` when I press the back button in MainActivity. Is there any solution like using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY`?

Comment: `onDestory` any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called `finish()` on it), or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()), before doing any operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `finish()` your `SubActivity` in `onBackPressed` to destroy it and go back to your `MainActivity`, instead of doing a `startActivity`.  In many cases, that is the behavior you'll get even if you don't implement `onBackPressed` yourself.  Your current code is starting a second `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I want to remain SubActivity in the back stack. So when MainActivity is destroyed, I want all the activities including SubActivity conduct onDestroy().

Comment: Can I ask why you want to add an additional activity to the back stack on the user hitting back?  Generally this would be quite unexpected for a user who expects to be taken back, not have more `Activity`s added.

Comment: In my SubActivity, it starts media player service. MainActivity plays a role in choosing music(there's a lot of music file), SubActivity shows play screen. So I don't want to finish the SubActivity until MainActivity is finished.

Comment: Um... is there any way do not conduct ```onDestroy()``` in SubActivity, when I press the back button in SubActivity?? I don't like to make the second MainActivity that you told me.

Comment: You could just have the user reenter the SubActivity and reconnect to the existing media playback.  It doesn't have to actually stay open.

Comment: Do you mean **reenter** to call ```onCreate()``` in SubActivity class? ```back button in SubActivity``` > ```SubActivity onDestroy()``` > ```reenter``` > ```SubActivity onCreate()```

Comment: Yes, that way you don't have to keep two `MainActivity`s

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed [here](https://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/how-to-clear-all-activity-stack-in-android) worked for me:

**In Java:-**

```
    Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
// set the new task and clear flags
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

**In Kotlin:-**

```
val i = Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity::class.java)
// set the new task and clear flags
i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
startActivity(i)
```